# Почему виснет сайт на итерации массива из бд?

Tags: php, wordpress

Получаю массив из базы данных

```
 $slides = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_slider`", ARRAY_A);
```

в базе две записи или более.
Далее обхожу массив циклом, в цикле подставляются нужные данные из базы для слайдера, например:

```
               <?php foreach($slides as $slide):?>
                    <div class="slide__container ibg">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/assets/img/slider/current/<?=$slide['img']?>" class="ibg_img" alt="">
                        <div class="slide_main__content-wrapper">
                            <div class="slide_main__content _container">
                                <div class="slide_main__content-type nodisplay">
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/assets/img/perform_no_rotate.png" alt="perform_no_rotate.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide_main__content-text">
                                    <div class="content-text__date">
                                        <span class="ff_gilroy_i def_color"><?=$slide['date_select_1'] ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content-text__title">
                                        <h2 class="ff_tenor"><?=$slide['title']?></h2>
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Текстовые данные подставляются в слайд, но сайт при этом не прогружается, только шапка и сам слайдер не полностью. Если из базы удаляю записи и оставляю только ОДНУ, то весь цикл отрабатывает корректно, и сайт прогружается полностью, и слайд добавляется в слайдер. Дебаг wp включен, и ошибок не показывает, так же вначале файла:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

которые ошибок не показывают.

Comment: Пробовали вывести на экран, что у вас прилетает после запроса в переменную $slides в случае, когда записей в БД больше одной?

Comment: Html-код недогруженой страницы посмотри. И ошибки в консоли браузера. А ошибки php смотри в логах.